# How to serve Review and Rating to google after algorithm update

Tags: seo, rich-snippets, structured-data, google-rich-snippets-tool

Recently, Google announced that it wont show Review rich snippets if they are "self-serving".

> When a review about entity A is placed on the website of entity A -
>   either directly in their markup or via an embedded 3rd party widget.
>   That’s why, with this change, we’re not going to display review rich
>   results anymore for the schema types LocalBusiness and Organization
>   (and their subtypes) in cases when the entity being reviewed controls
>   the reviews themselves.

Structure below was working until google update :

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "CreativeWork",
  "name": "Article Title",
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "4.2",
    "ratingCount": "20",
    "bestRating": "5",
    "worstRating": "1"
  }
}
```

I want to know what is the solution to get AggregateRating back?

Comment: It sounds like the markup isn't the issue.  You don't say what the reviews are reviewing.  You don't say what your relationship with that entity is.  You don't say where the reviews come from.